# Polarion - Display message box to the user

Tags: javascript, api, messagebox, polarion

I would like to display a warning message (with just an "OK" button) when transitioning from one status to another. I tried using a ScriptFunction in the workflow of the WI with the following code (display_message.js):

// Get work item
var workItem = workflowContext.getTarget();

// Get the first parameter - the message itself
var fieldMsg = arguments.getAsString("field.msg");

// Display message
Message(fieldMsg, 1);

But I get the error message that "Message" is unknown. I also tried with "setMessage(fieldMsg)". And I got the same. I found those two functions in RtLinkBuilder and IBuildEvent.
Any idea how to solve this?
Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for UI-features in Workflow functions and conditions.
In general Polarion Open API does not support UI features(except Formextensions, which should not write/modify content)
The only possibility is to throw an exception, but you cannot branch on this and you cannot transport any user-readable message (except the Exceptionname).